# Передача элемента одномерного массива в функцию

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Допустим, у меня есть функция f(...) и массив a[n]. Как мне передать элемент массива в функцию? И как должны быть записаны формальные параметры функции f()? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один элемент?

```
f(a[i]);
```

Весь массив?

```
f(a,n);
```

Поскольку массив низводится до указателя, отдельно следует передавать его размер.

Или вы хотите узнать что-то иное? тогда спрашивайте точнее...

Comment: Два элемента массива a[] нужно передать в фунцию f()

Comment: `f(a[i],a[j]);` Но вопрос настолько тривиален, что меня не покидает ощущение, что вы хотите спросить нечто иное, но не в состоянии правильно сформулировать, что именно...

Comment: Всё, что заставляет меня сомневаться - это как должны быть записаны формальные параметры функции f()..

Comment: `возвращаемый_тип f(тип_параметра_1 x1, тип_параметра_2 x2)` - примерно так.

Comment: Я так и писал. Но возвращает результат она не тот, который должна (если вручную пересчитать функцию с переданными ей элементами массива)

Comment: Знаете, надоело загадки разгадывать. Напишете нормальный вопрос - получите нормальный ответ, а без внятного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: Огромное спасибо, уже разобрался. Ошибка была в другом месте)